# fix needed regarding Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'substr' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, casting, substr

The script below currently used to extract URL and to perform an image swap on mouseover. However, I'm currently getting uncaught type error:

> cannot read property 'substr' of undefined

The code is:

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('.hover_box_wrapper').mouseenter(function(){
        var img_src = jQuery(this).parent().parent().parent().find('.hover2 img').attr('src');
        var img_src_s= img_src.substring(0,img_src.lastIndexOf("?"));
        var img_href = jQuery(this).parent().attr('href');
        var img_src_set = jQuery(this).parent().parent().parent().find('.hover2 img').attr('srcset');
        var src = jQuery('.center123').find('img').attr('src');
        var res = src.split(" ");
        var src_first = res[0];
         src_first = src_first.substring(0,src_first.lastIndexOf("?")); 

        jQuery('.center123').find('img').attr('src',img_src_s);
        jQuery('.center123').find('img').attr('srcset',src_first);

        //var img_html = jQuery('.center123').find('.vc_single_image-wrapper').html();
        //jQuery('.center123').find('.vc_single_image-wrapper').html('');
        jQuery('.center123').find('.vc_single_image-wrapper').html('<a href="'+ img_href + '"><img src="'+ img_src_s+'" srcset="'+ src_first +'" /></a>');
    });
});
```

Comment: Need to see your HTML code in order to debug and fix it.

Comment: hi, i've saved the page source here for your easy reference: http://dev.thesuit.sg/lcattertonasia/page-source.html

Comment: @BentoSet, please find the answer below, your issue is pretty much straightforward, you just have to be more attentive to your code, and to learn how to debug it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you error is hidden here, in this piece of code, if you'll debug it line by line:

```
var src = jQuery('.center123').find('img').attr('src');
var res = src.split(" ");
var src_first = res[0];
```

in case there's **no** elements found, you'll get no `src` attributes found, which equals to `undefined` value stored in `src_first` variable.

You need to introduce additional check of the result, which is stored within `res[0]`. `split(" ")` will work only on type `{String}`, it can't be applied to `undefined`.

The simplest additional check may be coded like:

```
// ...
var src = jQuery('.center123').find('img').attr('src');
if (! src) { // <== here's the additional check, the simplest case possible
    return;
}
var res = src.split(" ");
var src_first = res[0];
// ...
```

Comment: hi there, sorry i am not a developer and am not well versed in jquery.... thanks for taking a look at my question. may i know what exactly i need to do to fix the issue?

the site was working fine when it was on my development site; http://dev.thesuit.sg/lcattertonasia but its not working now when ported over to the actual server